# Errors during flutter web app initialization

Tags: flutter, error-handling, initialization

https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/initialization

On the above page, there is a detailed description of how the Flutter web app loads, and what the steps are. However, there is no information on how to handle errors that might happen during this initialization.

For example, in Chrome there were a couple of net::ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE errors when opening the app and it failed to load, leaving a blank white page behind, which is not great.

Is there a way to show some kind of error message if any error happens? Maybe by playing around the code in web/index.html?